# The header of products is not displayed

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

my problem is that the header of products is not displayed on the phone when scrolling, although if you check how it will be displayed on the phone via laptop then everything is ok. Can anyone help please?

https://svitlanavorobets.github.io/toster/comparison.html

Answer (score 0):

Can you try withi this:

```
<div class="header__top top-header" 
style="position: fixed; top: 0;width: 100%;">
```

---

```
<div class="header__bottom bottom-header" id="navbar" 
style="position: fixed; top: 50px;width: 100%;">
```

---

```
<main class="page-compare _container" 
style="margin-top: 52px !important;">
```

Please use css class for this.

Comment: I'm sorry, I wrote badly about the problem. Product headers are not displayed